Scrape calendar results
I'm looking to scrape historical data from:
https://www.racenet.com.au/results/horse-racing
the history is obtained by going to the "Select Date" tab and selecting a date and clicking on the "View Results" button.
You'll notice interacting with the calendar in this way does not change the URL, so I'm lost as to how to cycle through the calendar and bring up the schedule for a particular date and then how to access the results, i.e., when I select a date from the calendar manually and then "View Source" on the returned page, I don't see the links equivalent to the specific races.
Example: randomly select May 11 2021 from the calendar
Mackay (QLD) is the first track listed.
Right-clicking on this page and searching "Mackay" yields no match.
Manually clicking the first race, "R1", sees the URL change to:
https://www.racenet.com.au/results/horse-racing/mackay-20210511/smartstate-rentals-bm65-race-1
which is then fine for me to consume, it's the steps involved in cycling through the calendar dates and getting a handle on those race URLs that's my problem.
I'm hoping there's a solution in python, any tips/suggestions on how to solve this would be much appreciated.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Here's a more complete answer that will retrieve all of the horses running in each event at every meeting on the chosen day.
import requests
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

DATE = "2024-06-07"

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:126.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/126.0",
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "authorization": "Bearer none",
}

params = {
    "operationName": "meetingsIndexByStartEndDate",
    "variables": '{"startDate": "' + DATE + '", "endDate": "' + DATE + '", "limit": 100}',
    "extensions": '{"persistedQuery": {"version": 1, "sha256Hash": "998212fede87c9261e0f18e9d8ced2ed04a915453dcd64ae1b5cf5a72cf25950"}}',
}

response = requests.get("https://puntapi.com/graphql-horse-racing", params=params, headers=headers)

races = response.json()

for group in races["data"]["meetingsGrouped"]:
    for meeting in group["meetings"]:
        for event in meeting["events"]:
            time.sleep(5)
            print(" "+meeting["name"]+" — "+event["name"]+"\n")

            URL = "https://www.racenet.com.au/results/horse-racing/"+meeting["slug"]+"/"+event["slug"]

            print("URL: "+URL+"\n")

            response = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)

            soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

            names = soup.select("h4.selection-result__info-competitor-name")

            for name in names:
                print(name.get_text().strip())

            print()


Uses the underlying API to retrieve a list of meetings and events for a specific date.
Iterates over meetings and events, retrieving static HTML for each event and extracting the horses. Also gets meeting name and race name from the API response.

There's a lot more data in both the API response and the static HTML. You can rummage around in that and find everything you need.
The output looks like this:
 Ipswich — Tab Ipswich Cup Tickets On Sale Mdn Plate                                                                                                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
URL: https://www.racenet.com.au/results/horse-racing/ipswich-20240607/tab-ipswich-cup-tickets-on-sale-mdn-plate-race-1                                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
6. Vermeer                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
5. Salamancas                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
9. Luisana                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
8. Fionte                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
4. Himeji                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
7. Cassie's Girl                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
10. Kaytee Sunnyline                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
3. Turpin's Torment                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
2. Shambolic                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
1. Push Turbo                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
 Ipswich — Put It On Black Mdn Hcp                                                                                                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
URL: https://www.racenet.com.au/results/horse-racing/ipswich-20240607/put-it-on-black-mdn-hcp-race-2                                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
3. Find Your Own                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
4. Hydros                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
8. Look It's Lucy                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
9. Starspangle Planet                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
7. Literacy                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
1. Arnie's Army


This will dump all of the data for a specific date into a JSON file. Modify the definition of DATE to select other dates. Or put the whole thing into a function so that you can easily iterate over multiple dates.
The data returned by the API call can be accessed as a dictionary via response.json(). You can manipulate that to extract just the relevant data.
I like to dump it to an indented JSON file first though so that I can understand the structure and this informs how I would access the data that I need.
import requests
import json

DATE = "2024-06-07"

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:126.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/126.0",
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "authorization": "Bearer none",
}

params = {
    "operationName": "meetingsIndexByStartEndDate",
    "variables": '{"startDate": "' + DATE + '", "endDate": "' + DATE + '", "limit": 100}',
    "extensions": '{"persistedQuery": {"version": 1, "sha256Hash": "998212fede87c9261e0f18e9d8ced2ed04a915453dcd64ae1b5cf5a72cf25950"}}',
}

response = requests.get("https://puntapi.com/graphql-horse-racing", params=params, headers=headers)

with open(f"race-data-{DATE}.json", "wt") as file:
    file.write(json.dumps(response.json(), indent=2))

Examples of data scraped using this approach (they're big chunks of JSON, so I'm not going to paste them here):

2024-06-07 and
2024-06-06.


Although this code may provide the data that @JL89 is looking for, it does not answer the question which is how to scrape https://www.racenet.com.au/results/horse-racing

Thanks, this is almost perfect, however I notice only the first 4 horses show in the result. For example, Ipswich, Race 1 (https://www.racenet.com.au/results/horse-racing/ipswich-20240607/tab-ipswich-cup-tickets-on-sale-mdn-plate-race-1), your file has all the info required for horses Vermeer, Salamancas, Luisana, Fionte but doesn't capture details for Himeji, Cassie's Girl, Kaytee Sunnyline, Turpin's Torment, Shambolic, Push Turbo. Can your code be tweaked to accommodate?

@JL89 I'm pretty sure that we can get those data using a similar approach. IMHO using the API behind a dynamic site is generally a more efficient and direct way to get the data you need. I'll take a look at this a bit later!

To be clear though, after you have selected a date from the calendar, you get a list of races for that date. To get the data you're after I presume you're then clicking through on a specific race? Because I don't see the data for all horses on the race list view.

Correct, your code brings back some of the data for the first four horses in a single race. Clicking on a specific race's link will bring up all the horses and some additional data. If you're able to generate JSON for the specific race page that would be perfect. If not, I can still derive the URL from what you've already provided and go from there. Thanks again.

@JL89 I've posted a second, more complete answer that includes scraping the individual event pages. Those pages are static, so scraping is the correct approach rather than hitting an API.
